# MySQL select closest value

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing shipping rates and maximum weights, eg:

```
max_weight     shipping_cost
100            1.50
250            3.00
500            5.00
1000           8.50
30000          12.50
```

I want to be able to get the shipping rate based on the weight of the order, where the weight is less than `max_weight` in the table. So if the weight is 410, the shipping cost would be 5.00, if the weight is 2000 the shipping is 12.50 and so on.

Using `max_weight >= '" . $weight . "'` doesn't work as it just returns the first `max_weight` that's more than the weight, eg a weight of 683 returns 12.50 as the shipping cost.

How do I make sure it gets the correct `max_weight`?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` cleverly.

```
   WHERE weight < max_weight
ORDER BY max_weight ASC 
   LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I can't believe using order by didn't even cross my mind :| Thanks!